# It doesnt seem that jQuery clones events, but just the html/xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a test script i writing up as a demo, and I am building a template, but when i clone it, it doesnt seem to fire the event.

```
var $shifter = $("<a class='shifter'>^</a>");
$shifter.click(function(){
    alert("ping");
});
```

You can view my whole template at:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/drdCp/2/
Everything is done in Javascript, so the HTML contains just the sample form PRE-COMPONENTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.clone(true)](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone with events

Comment: (it also transfers `.data`)

Comment: INTERESTING!  Im going to have to use this more often.  I did not that was how it work.  Now i can build the template and then just do .clone(true) for when im iterating clones.
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Beat me to it, interestingly no "New Answer to this question" link appeared.